# SQL Server - Create Index on 2 Tables without FK

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a stored procedure that selects from a table called Milestone. It looks something like this:

```
SELECT PK_Milestone, MilestoneName, Step
FROM dbo.Milestone as M
INNER JOIN dbo.Process as P ON M.FK_Milestone_Process = P.PK_Process
WHERE P.ProcessID = @Input_ProcessID
  AND M.IsActive = 1
  AND P.IsActive = 1
```

And I read that in order to speed the retrieval of data, I have to create an Index so I tried creating one.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Milestone 
    ON Milestone (FK_Milestone_Process, IsActive)
```

However, I am not sure if my Index is correct. Should I create an Index on the columns of my `INNER JOIN`, on my `WHERE` clause, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume your filtering condition `p.ProcessID` is very selective (i.e. it selects very few rows from the table `dbo.Process`).

If it's the case, then I would create the following two indexes:

```
create index ix1 on dbo.Process (processID, isActive);

create index ix2 on dbo.Milestone (FK_Milestone_Process, isActive);
```

Comment: Can I also create another index on dbo.Process for the column PK_Process? Or is it unnecessary?

Comment: If the column `PK_Process` is the primary key of the table, there's already an index created for it.

Answer (score 2):

For this query:

```
SELECT PK_Milestone, MilestoneName, Step
FROM dbo.Milestone M INNER JOIN
     dbo.Process P
     ON M.FK_Milestone_Process = P.PK_Process
WHERE P.ProcessID = @Input_ProcessID AND
      M.IsActive = 1 AND
      P.IsActive = 1;
```

The best indexes are probably:  `Process(ProcessId, IsActive, PK_Process)` and `Milestone(FK_Milestone_Process, IsActive)`.

The first two keys in the `Process` index cover the `WHERE` clause.  The last key is for the `JOIN`.  The first key in the `Milestone` index is for the `JOIN` and the next is for filtering.

You can also add `MilestoneName` and `Step` to the respective indexes at the end, so the indexes *cover* the query.